# Battleship: Mean and variance of the number of distinct ships hit

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

I have the following problem, and I would like to know whether my approach is correct.

> Consider a round of the game 'Battleship'. Your opponent randomly places 3 ships on a 10 by 10 grid, where ship 1 has length 4, ship 2 has length 3 and ship 3 has length 2. The ships are not allowed to overlap. Suppose you fire a salvo of 5 simultaneous guess, which are a random sample without replacement from the total number of positions on the grid.
>
> Find the mean and variance of the number of distinct ships you hit.

My approach:

Let $X$ be the number of distinct ships hit, and $M$ be the number of ships missed. Then $X=3-M$. Let $I_i$ be and indicator random variable which takes on value 1 if the $i^{th}$ ship was hit and 0 otherwise. Then

$$
E(X) = 3-E(M) = 3-\sum_{i=1}^3 E(I_i)
$$
and
\begin{align}
Var(X) = Var(M) &= Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 I_i\right)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^3 Var(I_i) + 2 \sum_{i>j} Cov(I_i,I_j)
\end{align}

Thus, we have to find $E(I_i)$ and $E(I_iI_j)$ for all $i\in \{1,2,3\}$ and $j<i$. Let $l_i$ be the length of the $i^{th}$ ship, with $l\in \{2,3,4\}$. Let $n=10^2$ be the number of positions on the board.

I reasoned as follows. The $i^{th}$ ship occupies $l_i$ adjacent (linear) positions on the board. However, the probability of hitting or missing that ship is not affected by those restrictions, as the guesses are a random sample from all positions. The ship could be broken apart into $l_i$ pieces randomly scattered across the board, and nothing would change. Because of this, the board can be 'vectorized' to a vector of length $n$. Assume for convenience that the first $l_i$ elements of the vector is occupied by ship $i$. I have $5$ guesses. The $5$ elements that I guess and the $n-5$ that I don't guess can be permuted in $n!$ ways, all equally likely. The 'positive' permutations, i.e., those where none of the pieces of the ship and the guesses coincide can be obtained as follows. First,  there are $\binom{n-5}{l_i} l_i$ ways to choose $l_i$ elements from the $n-5$ elements which I didn't guess, place them at the first $l_i$ positions and permute them. Then, there are $(n-l_i)!$ ways to permuted the remaining $n-l_i$ elements. Hence,

$$E(I_i) = P(I_i=1) = \frac{1}{n!} \binom{n-5}{l_i}l_i \cdot (n-l_i)! = \frac{P_{n-l_i,5}}{P_{n,5}},$$

and similarly,

$$
E(I_iI_j) = P(I_i=1,I_j=1) = \frac{P_{n-l_i-l_j,5}}{P_{n,5}}
$$

Summing up all the terms, I obtain as a result $E(X)=0.43$ and $Var(X)=0.343$.

Comment: Well simulating the process I get $E(X)\approx 0.430$ and $Var(X)\approx 0.343$ , rounded to three sig figs, from $10^6$ replications. So the numerical value of your answer looks OK to me

Comment: @FredBarker Than you Fred. I also tried to simulate, but probably made some bug and got other values.

Comment: Doing some calculations on the errors in the simulation estimates, it appears that I was "lucky" with my results. The estimates can only be relied on to 2 significant figures. For both the sampling errors are of the order of $\pm 1$ in the third figure.